# How to allocate memory to pointer to a record? Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, pointers, getmem

I have this type:

```
type
  pTRegex_sec=^TRegex_sec;
  TRegex_sec = record
  secs: Array of pTRegex_sec;
  len: byte;
  hasSections: boolean;
  hasUnits: boolean;
  units: Array of TRegex_unit;
end;

type TRegex_assertions = record
  len: byte;
  secs: Array of TRegex_sec;
end;
```

I would like to allocate memory for the type TRegex_sec:

```
var Assertions: TRegex_assertions;
begin
  setlength(Assertions.secs, 1);
  GetMem(Assertions.secs[0], SizeOf(TRegex_sec));
end;
```

The error I have is "Incompatible types": `Assertions.secs[0]<-- here`

Another attempt, same error:

```
New(Assertions.secs[0]);
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TRegex_assertions.secs` field is a dynamic array of *records*, not an array of *pointers*. There is no need to use `GetMem()` to allocate that array, `SetLength()` already handles that for you.

However, the `TRegex_sec.secs` field is a dynamic array of *pointers*. Use `SetLength()` to allocate that array as needed, and then use `New()` to allocate individual `TRegex_sec` instances to populate it with:

```pascal
var
  Assertions: TRegex_assertions;
begin
  SetLength(Assertions.secs, 1);
  SetLength(Assertions.secs[0].secs, 1);
  New(Assertions.secs[0].secs[0]);
  ... 
end;
```